# Configure hapi, typescript, webpack, angular2 for electron

Tags: typescript, angular, webpack, electron, hapi.js

as part of crash course to web developement, I tried to setup desktop application with electron using angular2.
That sort of working, bundled with webpack, running ok.

I faced problem when I tried to integrate with HAPI, that failed miserably.
What I want is to run HAPI server from electron so I can interact with http requests in UI. Webpack rejects to pack hapi, saying that 
"you may need an appropriate loader to handle this type of file"..

I thought I could directly feed http requests into UI...

Is it possible at all to run HAPI inside web browser?
Should I be running it as separate module at electron level (inside main.js)?

iI have installed typings for hapi, did not work..

I put all stuff in github here,
https://github.com/EvgenyMuryshkin/xassist

Thanks,
Regards,
Evgeny.

Comment: considering that happy is a serverside (node) framework to build webservers, I don't think you can run it inside the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a http server framwework from within electron, either make http requests with a http client library that can work in the browser such as

- [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent)
- [fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch)
- [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Alternatively deploy a hapi based server with electron app to run locally on clients machine, either way hapi can't work in browser.

Comment: To expand on Simon's answer a bit, you are mixing up concepts. Angular (JavaScript & HTML) are static assets served by something like nginx. Hapi is a server side NodeJS framework a.k.a server or API with the whole setup usually referred to as "full stack" which includes a data source. I use Angular2 & Hapi every day but the two run independently of each other and communicate using libs like Simon mentioned amongst others like Socket.io Hapi can serve static assets but that does not include the electron framework which is in the end, serving static assets

Comment: Yes well put @d3viant0ne

Comment: I understand that they are server and client technologies, I just thought that as it is desktop application, I can run both, like i can run OWIN server inside WPF desktop application.... anyway, that was fun exercise.. there is some way to do that with electron-workers, i will give it a try.. thanks for help.

Comment: @Evgeny - Just thing of Electron as a lib filling in for Chrome. At almost every level ( less service workers ) same application architecture rules apply

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to make it running due to the bug in my code. This is really bizzare coincidence, but HAPI apparently can run inside Electron (browser) application.

What I did is I used webpack with target "node-webkit" to transpile my server code. Then I included result JS directly into browser and it works. The only issue is how to pass objects between them - I simply store everything in window object, not really good approach, but should be fine for my application.